# i am unable to move from one jsp page to another jsp page in spring mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, netbeans

This is the error I get.Even though the application starts with the index.jsp page but its unable to move to the login.jsp page.[image]

This is the project structure.[image]

This is the Dispatcher Servlet.[[image]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6eKz.png)

This is web.xml file.[image]

This is the index.jsp file with attribute action of form element = "/KashmirConnect/signUp" which takes it to @RequestMapping("/signUp")[image]

This is the controller class with one method[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.KashmirConnect</groupId>
<artifactId>KashmirConnect</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>KashmirConnect</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: post code as text in your post instead of images

Comment: @Nihal Actually I am new to using stackoverflow. Bdw , which specific code you want me to post or are you talking in general . I thought images would illustrate my problem well . That's why

Comment: what do you want me to do now @Nihal

Comment: Did you try to remove the /KashmirConnect/ part from the form action and only submit to "/signUp"?

Comment: Yes , I didn't help . It shows the same error @Avijit Barua

Comment: I tried that also @Sebastian

Comment: @mamoon check recent answer.

Comment: Thowing the same error @Avijit Barua

Comment: Please post your pom.xml

Comment: how do I post it @Avijit Barua

Comment: Click edit on your post and  copy paste your pom.xml

Comment: I have made edits , you have a look @Avijit Barua

Comment: @mamoon, I have edited my answer. Perhaps there is a version problem. Check again with new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this instruction

1.Move your `index.jsp` in Views folder

```
2. write your web.xml like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>


            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>
            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>
        </web-app>

3. Now in controller class write a method like 

     @RequestMapping("/")
       public ModelAndView index()
        {
          ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
          return modelAndView;
        }
```

And you can check by replacing your `pom.xml` with this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    <groupId>com.KashmirConnect</groupId>
<artifactId>KashmirConnect</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


        <dependencies>

    <!--Spring dependency-->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--Hibernate Dependency-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--Extra Dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.41</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

And another thing in your `DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` replace your first bean with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation=
                   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
```

Comment: I tried it . It throws the same error. This time it doesn't even open the index page @Avijit Barua

Comment: Checked new answer ?

Comment: this is what it is reporting , Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getResponseStatus()Lorg/springframework/http/HttpStatus;  @Avijit Barua

Comment: @mamoon Everything is working fine in my project. I don't know what happened to your project.

Comment: Whatever you said , I did the same, maybe I should create a new project then. what do you suggest @Avijit Barua

Comment: I will suggest you to use `Eclipse` or `Intellij IDEA`

Comment: Is it the problem with netbeans . I have been programming on it from past year though I am new to spring MVC @Avijit Barua

Comment: I appreciate your help.Bdw , if I start with eclipse how do I manage my project with respect to jsp files , controller classes , JavaScript files , CSS files and others . I mean where to place all of them(structure). Please if you could explain a bit @Avijit Barua

Comment: your changes worked, the application is running. What was the problem. Was it about dependencies that I had included or the namespaces . Is there a relation between the two . If I start with a project in mind , which dependencies should I choose as there are so many. Also , cannot I keep the index.jsp out of the views folder and include its entry in the welcome-file-list tag as I was doing earlier. Anyways Regards @Avijit Barua